# Android TextView getMaxHeight() for API less than 16

Tags: android, android-view

My current min API level is 14. `TextView.getMaxHeight()` is available at a minimum API level of 16. How would I get the same result in API 14?

Comment: There is no View.getMaxHeight(), nor a View.getMaximumHeight(). Did you mean View.getMinimumHeight()?

Comment: Or maybe `ImageView#getMaxHeight()`?

Comment: It exists for LinearLayout.

Comment: Not according to my IDE, or any source for LinearLayout I can find.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, meant TextView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getMaxHeight()